# Is there a way to fit an even function using only odd functions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, regression

I was wondering if there is a way to make an infinite series of odd functions equal to an even function. For example, I would like to know if the next equation is valid

$$\cos(x)=\beta_1x+\beta_2x^3+\beta_3x^5+\beta_4x^7+\cdots$$

Is there any proof that says that is possible?

Comment: How do you approximate exactly?

Comment: Approximate in which sense, on which domain? Any linear combination of odd functions is odd, so for most meanings of "approximate", if the domain is symmetric about $0$, you can't approximate a nonzero even function by odd functions.

Comment: In other words, Goryani, how do you think you are going to get even powered terms, if you only have odd powered terms available?

Comment: The zero function is both even and odd.

Comment: By exact approximation I mean finding an infinite series of odd functions that are equal to an even function. @imranfat what you are asking me is exactly my question. Is there any proof about it?

Comment: @Gorayni: The proof is little more than the definition of odd and even.

Comment: I am not aware of a formal proof, but what Daniel mentioned makes lots of sense to me. With linear combinations, odd powers make odd powers and not even powers

Comment: "A formal proof" that a non-zero even function cannot be uniformly approximated to arbitrary accuracy by an odd function simply requires the triangle inequality to be appropriately applied at a point where the even function is non-zero (and the associated negative point)

Answer (score 3):

As Daniel Fischer says, any linear combination of odd functions is still odd.  So if $\cos (2\pi )=1$ is approximated well, your approximation will satisfy $\cos (-2\pi)\approx -1$, which is rather far from $\cos (-2\pi )=1$  This does not strike me as a good approximation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to represent $\cos x$ with high accuracy with an odd powered series in a domain interval that is either strictly positive or strictly negative, see the answer to [Approximating a continuous function on a positive interval with a series with arbitrary prescribed powers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506286/approximating-a-continuous-function-on-a-positive-interval-with-a-series-with-ar) . I think this is about the best that you can do. As other answers/comments alluded, if you have an odd powered series and $0$ is in the domain interval for which you want to approximate, then you can't get a good approximation everywhere in the interval because for your power series you must have $f(0) = 0$ and also $f(-x) = -f(x)$ even though $\cos 0 = 1$ and $\cos (-x) = \cos x$.