# Approximating a continuous function on a positive interval with a series with arbitrary prescribed powers?

Tags: real-analysis

This relates to a recent question which asked whether it was possible to approximate $\cos x$ with a series for an odd function (series with odd-powered terms). It occurred to me the answer maybe yes is we restricted to a finite positive interval and ask for approximation instead of absolute equality.

So here's my question. Suppose we have a pretty nice function $f$ (say, continuous) defined on a positive interval $[a,b]$ ($a,b > 0$). Suppose also we are told an infinite sequence of which powers $0 \leq n_1 < n_2 < n_3 < \ldots$ we are allowed to use (all $n_j$ non-negative integers). For $\epsilon > 0$, can we find coefficients $a_{n_j}$ defining a series

$$\hat{f}(x) = \sum_j a_{n_j} x^{n_j}$$

so that $||f-\hat{f}||_\infty < \epsilon$, where the $L_\infty$ distance is computed over the interval $[a,b]$? If we can't, then are there restrictions on $a,b$ and the sequence of powers which makes it possible, such as $\sum_j 1/n_j$ diverges, and/or $a,b$ are both greater than $1$ or both less than $1$? Or maybe also/alternatively changing the norm for the approximation error?

Comment: I'd think that the result is that you can approximate every continuous function on the interval if and only if $\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n_k} = \infty$, since that's the condition of the Müntz-Szasz theorem, where $n_1 = 0$ is included, and the interval is $[0,1]$. If we have the constant $1$, I'd be surprised if the theorem wouldn't hold for any $[0,b]$. Without the constant $1$, I think $a > 0$ makes every function approximable without the constant.

Comment: @DanielFischer You have a knack for answering questions either entirely or almost entirely, without actually posting an answer. =) I'll definitely up-vote and accept this as an answer especially if you can work out the detail about not needing the constant if $a > 0$.

Comment: Moreover, "Lipschitz" does not add anything since the Lipschitz functions are dense in $\mathcal C([a,b])$. However, there may be a hidden subtlety in the question: the series defining $\widehat f(x)$ may not converge uniformly (nor in any $L_p$ norm); and if this is allowed then one cannot apply Müntz theorem because the partial sums of the series do not approximate $\widehat f$.

Comment: I don't know if it's correct, that's why it's a comment, not an answer. Could be that Müntz-Szasz really needs the upper bound $\leqslant 1$. (Looking if I can see if I can prove my thoughts right or wrong.)

Comment: @Etienne Sure, I was typing in a hurry before thinking carefully so I'll remove Lipschitz.

Comment: As for the second part of my comment, just forget it: it was completely ridiculous since we are dealing with power series...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we have a sequence $0 \leqslant n_1 < n_2 < n_3 < \dotsc$ of admissible exponents (not necessarily integers), then the linear subspace of $C([a,b])$, for $0 < a < b$, generated by the functions $t\mapsto t^{n_k}$ is dense if and only if

$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n_k} = \infty.\tag{1}$$

If the lower bound of the interval is $a = 0$, then $n_1 = 0$ is necessary.

If $a > 0$ and $n_1 > 0$, the function $\psi \colon t \mapsto t^{-n_1}$ is continuous, bounded, and bounded away from zero, so $f$ can be uniformly approximated by a linear combination of the $t^{n_k}$ if and only if $f\cdot \psi$ can be uniformly approximated by a linear combination of the $t^{n_k-n_1}$, and $(1)$ isn't changed by substituting $n_k$ with $n_k - n_1$.

So we can, without loss of generality assume that $n_1 = 0$.

Then a small variation of the proof of the Müntz-Szasz theorem given in Rudin, Real And Complex Analysis, 15.26, pp. 313/314 in the third edition, namely replacing the function

$$f(z) = \int_{[0,1]} t^z \,d\mu(t)$$

by

$$\tilde{f}(z) = b^{-z}\int_{[a,b]} t^z\,d\mu(t)$$

for a complex Borel measure $\mu$ on $[a,b]$ that annihilates all $t^{n_k}$, yields the result that the closure of the subspace generated by the $t^{n_k}$ contains all $t^k$ and hence all polynomials, and by Weierstraß' theorem all of $C([a,b])$.

Answer (score 0):

The same sort of argument about positive and negative powers applies.  The Legendre polynomials are orthonormal and complete on $[-1,1]$, which says that you can't approximate any one of them well in terms of the rest.  Using linear algebra techniques, you can change the basis to the monomials in $x$.  The (finite approximation to the) transformation matrix is even triangular, so easy to invert.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, and I totally see the potential issue if the domain interval is allowed to include both positive and negative numbers (e.g. trying to approximate $\cos x$ on $[-2\pi,2\pi]$ with an odd-power function power series). I'm proposing considering restrictions that the finite domain interval $[a,b]$ satisfies $a>0 $ (and possibly $b < 1$ as well), or alternatively $b > a > 1$.

Comment: You can rescale any finite interval to any other, so that doesn't matter.  Multiplying by $e^{-x}$ or $e^{-x^2}$ lets you handle infinite ones as well.  The theory of orthogonal polynomials still applies-just the specific polynomials change.

Comment: @RossMillikan But the functions we use here for the approximation are not mutually orthogonal. That changes the game. One can skip some exponents and still have a dense span.

Comment: @DanielFischer:  Yes, if the exponents are not integral these theorems do not apply.

Comment: Even if they're integral. The Müntz-Szasz theorem doesn't require any non-integral exponent.